# Upgrading the existing database in a PHP system

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1

I'm working on a software solution which was written using PHP Symfony with mysql database. When we do upgrades to the existing product what we use now is copping the existing database to a new database and do the upgrade standing on the new database. But the current method of asking the user to copy the existing database does not seem to be the professional way to do an upgrade.

Is there any standard way of doing that automatically and preserve the consistency of the old database? Please help me on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of symfony are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a copy of the tables with a different table prefix (like updateAttempt_) and then if everything goes well delete the old ones and rename the new ones to the old ones.

Although, If you're doing this to make sure the data isn't corrupted in the event something goes wrong.. isn't that what TRANSACTIONS are for?